# MySQL DATETIME sort with virtual datetable

Tags: mysql, sorting, date, datetime

I have a table with some events in conjunction with timestamp as DATETIME.
Now I want to have a statistic about my data, e.g. how much events per day... In some cases I don´t have events every day and of course I don´t get in my statistic that days with no existens entries.

```
| id | DATE           | COUNT      |
| 1  | 2014-09-06     | 1          |
| 2  | 2014-09-07     | 8          |
| 3  | 2014-09-10     | 2          |
| 4  | 2014-09-14     | 78         |
```

So i wrote a little script who generates me a query to solv that problem. It generates a virtual table with my days i want to know and do a LEFT OUTER JOIN with my event table. 
So i will got all dates without gaps! The query looks like this e.g.:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d.date, '%d.%m.%Y') as datum, COUNT(l.id) as anzahl 
FROM
( 
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('25.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('26.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('27.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL 
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('28.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL 
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('29.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL 
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('30.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL 
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01.12.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date
) as d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN events l ON d.date = DATE(l.date) 
GROUP BY datum 
ORDER BY datum DESC
```

This query works absolute perfectly and i have also dates with no data in my statistic.

But now comes the real problem i have: the sorting doesn´t work! I got some weird output. I have no idea what the problem is. The output looks like this:

```
| DATE          | COUNT |
| 31.10.2014    | 0     |
| 30.11.2014    | 5     |
| 30.10.2014    | 0     |
| 29.11.2014    | 0     |
| 29.10.2014    | 0     |
| 28.11.2014    | 0     |
| 28.10.2014    | 0     |
| 27.11.2014    | 0     |
| 27.10.2014    | 0     |
| 26.11.2014    | 0     |
| 26.10.2014    | 0     |
| 25.11.2014    | 1     |
| 25.10.2014    | 0     |
| 24.11.2014    | 1     |
| 24.10.2014    | 0     |
| 23.11.2014    | 0     |
| 23.10.2014    | 0     |
| 22.11.2014    | 0     |
| 22.10.2014    | 0     |
| 21.11.2014    | 1     |
| 21.10.2014    | 0     |
| 20.11.2014    | 0     |
| 20.10.2014    | 0     |
| 19.11.2014    | 2     |
| 19.10.2014    | 0     |
| 18.11.2014    | 0     |
| 18.10.2014    | 0     |
| 17.11.2014    | 0     |
| 17.10.2014    | 0     |
| 16.11.2014    | 0     |
```

So what´s wrong with my query? I have conscious use the function STR_TO_DATE i got a "real" date format. Normaly the sorting should work with it, isn´t it?

Comment: If it was me, I wouldn't touch date formatting until I was back client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is your eyes see them as dates, but in your quesry they're strings so they are correctly sorted as string with the *day* and *month* first. Try having anotehr field formated for sorting and use that for the sort.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d.date, '%d.%m.%Y') as datum, DATE_FORMAT(d.date, '%Y.%m.%d') as sortdatum, COUNT(l.id) as anzahl 
FROM
( 
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('25.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('26.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('27.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL 
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('28.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL 
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('29.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL 
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('30.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL 
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01.12.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date
) as d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN events l ON d.date = DATE(l.date) 
GROUP BY datum 
ORDER BY sortdatum DESC
```

Comment: THX for your help. I combined your solution with sunysen's idea. Now I use "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(d.date) as sortdatum" as sorting.

Answer (score 0):

```
please it **unix_timestamp**

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d.date, '%d.%m.%Y') as datum, COUNT(l.id) as anzahl 
    FROM
    ( 
    SELECT STR_TO_DATE('25.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL
    SELECT STR_TO_DATE('26.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL
    SELECT STR_TO_DATE('27.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL 
    SELECT STR_TO_DATE('28.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL 
    SELECT STR_TO_DATE('29.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL 
    SELECT STR_TO_DATE('30.11.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date UNION ALL 
    SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01.12.2014', '%d.%m.%Y') as date
    ) as d 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN events l ON unix_timestamp(d.date) = unix_timestamp(l.date)
    GROUP BY datum 
    ORDER BY datum DESC
```